# What am I doing wrong when getting this user input?

Tags: c, scanf, newline, c-strings, fgets

I am not understanding why the user who runs this program does not get an option to enter the students full name after they selected #4 on the menu... It prompts for all of the other variables of the struct, but it skips over the first one.

I have just been trying out random things, so I apologize if this code looks like a mess, I can hardly read it myself at this point.  We are not allowed to use arrays in this project, which is why I am doing all these weird things with pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Ok, first we must make a struct that holds these things:
//  StudentID
//  Class Name
//  ClassID (like INET3101)
//  StudentFullName


struct record {
    int studentID;
    char *class_name;
    char *classID;
    char *full_name;
};

int num_rec = 0;
void add_record(struct record);
void remove_record(struct record);
void print_record(struct record);

struct record *database;



void add_record(struct record addTemp){

    num_rec++;
    if (num_rec ==1) {
        database = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
        memcpy(database, &addTemp, sizeof(struct record));
    }
    else {
        struct record *tempMem = malloc(sizeof(struct record) * num_rec);
        struct record *mover = database;
        struct record *head = tempMem;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i< num_rec; i++){
            memcpy(tempMem++, mover++, sizeof(struct record));  
        }
        memcpy(--tempMem, &addTemp, sizeof(struct record));
        free(database);
        database = head;

    }
}

void remove_record(struct record removeTemp){
    if (num_rec == 0){
        printf("There is nothing to delete here!");
        return;
    }

    else{

        struct record *tempMem= malloc(sizeof(struct record) * num_rec-1);
        struct record *mover = database;
        struct record *head = tempMem;
        int i;

                for (i = 0; i < num_rec-1; i++){
            memcpy(tempMem, &removeTemp, sizeof(struct record));
        }
        memcpy(--tempMem, &removeTemp, sizeof(struct record));
        free(database);
        database = head;
        num_rec--;

    }
}
    

void printRecords(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_rec; i++) {  
        int k = i + 1;
        printf("Student #%d\n", k);
        fprintf(stderr, "Student full name: %s\n", (database + i)->full_name);
        fprintf(stderr, "Student ID: %d\n", (database + i)->studentID);
        fprintf(stderr, "Class name: %s\n", (database + i)->class_name);
        fprintf(stderr, "Class ID: %s\n", (database)->classID);
        printf("\n");
    }
}




// }


// 1. print all records
// 2. print number of records
// 3. print size of database
// 4. add record
// 5. delete record
// 6. print number of accesses to a database
// 7. exit



int main(){

    int BUFSIZE = 100;
    struct record ultimate;

    static int accesses=0; 
    int choice=0;

    while (true) {
        printf("1. print all records \n");
        printf("2. print number of records \n");
        printf("3. print size of database \n");
        printf("4. add record \n");
        printf("5. delete record \n");
        printf("6. print number of accesses to a database \n");
        printf("7. exit \n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    
        switch (choice){
            case 1: 
            ;
            
            printf("This is our current database of records: ");
            if (num_rec == 0){
                printf("Oh... It looks like the data base is currently empty.\n");
                accesses++;
                break;
            }
            else{
                printRecords();
                accesses++;
                break;
            }
            
            case 2:
                ;
                printf("The current number of student records is: %d records\n", num_rec);
                accesses++;


            // 3. print size of database
            case 3:
                ;
                int size_database;
                int size_struct = sizeof(struct record);
                size_database = size_struct * num_rec;
                printf("The size of our database is %i\n", size_database);
                break;
            
            // 4. add record
            case 4:
                ;
                char *buf1 = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZE);
                char *buf2 = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZE);
                char *buf3 = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZE);
                char *buf4 = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZE);
                
                
                struct record ultimat;
                

                printf("Please enter this students Full Name: \n");
                fgets(buf1, BUFSIZE, stdin);
                if ((strlen(buf1) > 0) && (buf1[strlen (buf1) - 1] == '\n'))
                    buf1[strlen (buf1) - 1] = '\0';
                ultimat.full_name = malloc(strlen(buf1)+1);
                strcpy(ultimat.full_name, buf1);

                int id;
                printf("Please enter this students Student ID: \n");
                fgets(buf2, BUFSIZE, stdin);
                if ((strlen(buf2) > 0) && (buf2[strlen (buf2) - 1] == '\n'))
                    buf2[strlen (buf2) - 1] = '\0';
                ultimat.studentID = id;

                printf("Please enter the Class Name: \n");
                fgets(buf3, BUFSIZE, stdin);
                if ((strlen(buf3) > 0) && (buf3[strlen (buf3) - 1] == '\n'))
                    buf3[strlen (buf3) - 1] = '\0';
                ultimat.class_name = malloc(strlen(buf3)+1);
                strcpy(ultimat.class_name, buf3);

                printf("Please enter this students Class ID: \n");
                fgets(buf4, BUFSIZE, stdin);
                if ((strlen(buf4) > 0) && (buf4[strlen (buf4) - 1] == '\n'))
                    buf4[strlen (buf4) - 1] = '\0';
                ultimat.classID = malloc(strlen(buf4)+1);
                strcpy(ultimat.classID, buf4);

                add_record(ultimat);
                printf("Alright, I added this student to the database! \n");
                
                free(buf1);
                free(buf2);
                free(buf3);
                free(buf4);
                
                accesses++;
                break;
            
            // 5. delete record
            case 5:
                ;
                remove_record(ultimate);
                printf("Alright! I got the student at the top of the list deleted! \n");
                break;

            // 6. print number of accesses to a database
            case 6:
                ;
                printf("The current number of data base accesses is: %d acesses\n", accesses);
                break;

            case 7:
                exit(0);
        }
    }return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix a [mre]. This is guaranteed way more code than needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: "*so I apologize if this code looks like a mess, I can hardly read it myself at this point*". No need to apologise. Instead just please put in the effort to clean it up before posting it. Please see what is required: [mre].

Comment: You also might want to have a look at [ask]

Comment: *We are not allowed to use arrays in this project, which is why I am doing all these weird things with pointers.* So your instructor is actively teaching you to write unreadable, unmaintainable code.  Mad props to him.

Comment: You know, if `database` is a pointer to a number of `record` structures (as it appears that it is), you can write `database[i].class_name`, and you're not using arrays anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: _We are not allowed to use arrays in this project_ that is hard to do in practice; any contiguous data is an array. So . . . not allowed to use char arrays (strings)? `BUFSIZE` is an array. All must be linked lists!

Comment: You could simplify the code in `add_record` considerably by learning about `realloc`.

Comment: This could be dupe hammered with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that you need to remove before the first call of `fgets`

```
fgets(buf1, BUFSIZE, stdin);
```

Otherwise an empty string will be entered.

You could do it for example the following way

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, where would this while loop go?  I also realized that while I was editing this code made a mistake with the second input.  I am fixing that as well, just letting you know that I am aware if you also noticed.

Comment: @zujika The while loop should precede the first call of fgets after the case label 4:.

Comment: OHHH.  I see.  Thank you so much for explaining!  I would upvote if this account was allowed to!  Thank you very much.

Comment: @zujika Just select the answer as the best answer to close the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer